# TinyMCE bug via jquery load

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, tinymce, jquery-load

I have this kind of strange bug when I load tinymce via jquery `load`,

[image]

**After** the **first time** I click the dropdown to select one item from the list **(bullet list**, **number list**, **style list**, **paragraph list**), I get the bug as shown in the image when I reload the form via jquery load.

Any idea?

Comment: i strongly suggest not to use the tinymce jQuery build, it is far slower and a source of trouble!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is attaching the drop down elements to the body tag instead of within the editor you have created.  While this fixes some IE issue, it fails to deal with editor dom elements being loaded dynamically, stranding the drop down element on the page.

When loading/unloading an editor, remove all tinymce drop menus on the page via jQuery:

```
$(".mceListBoxMenu").remove();
```

I have tested this solution, and it works fine.